# ToC showing page number and then the chapter title

Tags: table-of-contents, xetex, lyx, memoir

I would like to have the Table of Contents of the book I am editing showing first the pages of the chapters and then the chapter titles. Something like this book: 
[image]

I am working with XeTeX (through LyX) and my document class is Memoir.

Comment: Do you want this behaviour just for chapter entries or for all sectional units in the ToC? Which document class are you using?

Comment: Hello. My ToC is made up of Parts and Chapters, there are no other sections in the book.

The document class is Memoir.

Comment: So, just to be sure, this is to apply to parts and chapter entries, or just to chapter entries?

Comment: Parts and chapters, you are right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one possibility (chapter number for unnumbered chpaters have been included before the corresponding titles, as has been requested in a comment):

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\renewcommand\partnumberline[1]{}
\renewcommand\chapternumberline[1]{#1~\raisebox{.2ex}{\scalebox{0.75}{\textbullet}~}}
\renewcommand\cftpartpagefont{\huge\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cftpartfont{\LARGE\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cftchapterpagefont{\normalfont\large\itshape}
\renewcommand\cftchapterfont{\normalfont}

\newlength\ToCindent
\setlength\ToCindent{4em}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\l@part}[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >-2\relax
    \cftpartbreak
    \begingroup
      {\leftskip0pt\noindent
       \interlinepenalty\@M
       \leavevmode
       \parbox[t]{\ToCindent}{\makebox[2em][r]{\cftpartpagefont #2}\hfill}%
       \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\ToCindent\relax}{\cftpartfont #1}%
       }
      \par\nobreak
        \global\@nobreaktrue
        \everypar{\global\@nobreakfalse\everypar{}}%
    \endgroup
  \fi}

\newcommand*{\l@mychap}[3]{%
  \def\@chapapp{#3}
  \vskip2ex%
  \par%
  \noindent\parbox[t]{\ToCindent}{\makebox[2em][r]{\cftchapterpagefont#2}\hfill}%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\ToCindent\relax}{\cftchapterfont#1}\par%
}

\renewcommand*{\l@chapter}[2]{%
  \l@mychap{#1}{#2}{\chaptername}%
}

\renewcommand*{\l@appendix}[2]{%
  \l@mychap{#1}{#2}{\appendixname}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\part{A test part}
\chapter{Test chapter with a really long title spanning several lines just for the example}
\chapter{Another test chapter}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{A test unnumbered chapter}
\chapter{Another test chapter with an interesting title}
\part{Another test part}
\chapter{Test chapter with a really long title spanning several lines just for the example}
\chapter{Another test chapter}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Another test unnumbered chapter}
\chapter{Another test chapter with an interesting title}
\part{Yet another test part}
\chapter{Test chapter with a really long title spanning several lines just for the example}
\chapter{Another test chapter}
\chapter{Another test chapter with an interesting title}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I add here another option showing the page number and chapter number separated by a bullet, as was originally required in the comment; I prefer the previous solution since this one might result in confusion:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\renewcommand\partnumberline[1]{}
\renewcommand\chapternumberline[1]{\makebox[0pt][l]{%
  \llap{\raisebox{.2ex}{\scalebox{0.75}{\textbullet}}\,#1\hspace{1.2em}}}}
\renewcommand\cftpartpagefont{\huge\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cftpartfont{\LARGE\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cftchapterpagefont{\normalfont}
\renewcommand\cftchapterfont{\normalfont}

\newlength\ToCindent
\setlength\ToCindent{4.5em}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\l@part}[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >-2\relax
    \cftpartbreak
    \begingroup
      {\leftskip0pt\noindent
       \interlinepenalty\@M
       \leavevmode
       \parbox[t]{\ToCindent}{\makebox[2em][r]{\cftpartpagefont #2}\hfill}%
       \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\ToCindent\relax}{\cftpartfont #1}%
       }
      \par\nobreak
        \global\@nobreaktrue
        \everypar{\global\@nobreakfalse\everypar{}}%
    \endgroup
  \fi}

\newcommand*{\l@mychap}[3]{%
  \def\@chapapp{#3}
  \vskip2ex%
  \par%
  \noindent\parbox[t]{\ToCindent}{\makebox[2em][r]{\cftchapterpagefont#2}\hfill}%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\ToCindent\relax}{\cftchapterfont#1}\par%
}

\renewcommand*{\l@chapter}[2]{%
  \l@mychap{#1}{#2}{\chaptername}%
}

\renewcommand*{\l@appendix}[2]{%
  \l@mychap{#1}{#2}{\appendixname}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\part{A test part}
\chapter{Test chapter with a really long title spanning several lines just for the example}
\chapter{Another test chapter}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{A test unnumbered chapter}
\chapter{Another test chapter with an interesting title}
\part{Another test part}
\chapter{Test chapter with a really long title spanning several lines just for the example}
\chapter{Another test chapter}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Another test unnumbered chapter}
\chapter{Another test chapter with an interesting title}
\part{Yet another test part}
\chapter{Test chapter with a really long title spanning several lines just for the example}
\chapter{Another test chapter}
\chapter{Another test chapter with an interesting title}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\ToCindent` length controls the separation between page numbers and titles.

Comment: Thank you for the solution!

Would be possible to add the chapter number before the chapter title for numbered chapters? Maybe something like a middot (·) might be useful to separate pages from chapter number.

Comment: @CatoPhilosophus please see my updated answer. I included the chapter numbers as part of the entry (and changed the font for chapter page numbers), as I think this is better to avoid confusions with the page numbers.

Comment: @CatoPhilosophus I added another option to my answer showing the layout you suggested in your comment; I personally find the first option less confusing.

Comment: Nice solution! I prefer the first solution as well. I wonder if this can be made to work with other classes (like Koma-Script).