# Add a vertical line between chapters/sections and page number in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

In a document using the `memoir` class, I am trying to draw a vertical line down the whole table between the page number and text.

My requirements (so far only one remains, which is the question):

- Have a Table of contents including Chapters and Sections (OK)
- Have no Chapter or Section Numbers (just the text) (OK)
- Have the page number to the left, the item text to the right (OK)
- Allow a slightly different style between Chapter and Section texts (OK)
- **A vertical line between the two** <= NOT OK

Basically, I'm trying to emulate the line in this table of contents:
[image: (Table of Contents: Robert E. Seamans' "Project Apollo", 2007)]

This is what I have with my MWE:
[image: Table of contents with my MWE]

But I have no idea how to create the vertical line in such a way as to be the exact height of the table of contents (which will potentially span more than one page)

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

% Clear Chapter and Section numbers
\renewcommand\chapternumberline[1]{}
\renewcommand\numberline[1]{}

% Prepare a length to indent the lot
\newlength\ToCindent
\setlength\ToCindent{0.3\textwidth}

\makeatletter

% Put pagenumbers and item texts where they should go
\newcommand*{\l@mytocentry}[3]{%
    \bigskip
    \par%
    \noindent\parbox[c]{\ToCindent}{\makebox[\dimexpr\ToCindent-2em][r]{\Large#2}\hfill}%
    \parbox[c]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\ToCindent\relax}{#1}%
}

% Create the items (with different styles)
\renewcommand*{\l@chapter}[2]{%
    \l@mytocentry{\Huge#1}{#2}{\chaptername}%
}
\renewcommand*{\l@section}[2]{%
    \l@mytocentry{\Large#1}{#2}{\sectionname}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\frontmatter%
\tableofcontents*

\mainmatter%

\chapter{Welcome}
\section{A Section}
\section{Another Section}
\chapter{Hello}
\section{Yet another section}
\section{Yet another section}
\chapter{World}
\section{Yet another section}

\end{document}
enter code here
```

I've tried:

- Making a table with pages in one column, text in the other and a vertical line between, but I can only get each line, and don't know how to loop through them to put the page number to one side, the text to another - in any case I'm hesitant to try because I'm afraid it would be reinventing the wheel
- Inspired by [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125613/toc-showing-page-number-and-then-the-chapter-title) I've gotten this far but have no idea how to do the line...

These questions helped me get this far but I haven't found one that allows this vertical line I need:

- [Page number before Chapter title in the Table of Contents with memoir](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55607/page-number-before-chapter-title-in-the-table-of-contents-with-memoir)
- [ToC showing page number and then the chapter title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125613/toc-showing-page-number-and-then-the-chapter-title)

## Update:

The accepted answer resolved my question. For completeness, here is how I ended up implementing it to ensure the line was centered. (I added a variable to `mytocentry` and added the line between my elements)

```
\newcommand{\vertrule}{$\smash{\rule[-2.3em]{0.2mm}{13mm}}$}
\newcommand*{\l@mytocentry}[3]{%
    \bigskip
    \par%
    \noindent\parbox[c]{\ToCindent}{\makebox[\dimexpr\ToCindent-1em][r]{\Large#2}\hfill}%
    \parbox[c]{1em}{\vertrule\hfill}%
    \parbox[c]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\ToCindent\relax}{#1}%
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this revised version of your MWE (for which thank you).

```
% memtocprob.tex SE 547344

\documentclass{memoir}

% Clear Chapter and Section numbers
\renewcommand\chapternumberline[1]{}
\renewcommand\numberline[1]{}

% Prepare a length to indent the lot
\newlength\ToCindent
\setlength\ToCindent{0.3\textwidth}

\makeatletter

% Put pagenumbers and item texts where they should go
\newcommand*{\l@mytocentry}[3]{%
    \bigskip
    \par%
    \noindent\parbox[c]{\ToCindent}{\makebox[\dimexpr\ToCindent-2em][r]{\Large#2}\hfill}%
    \parbox[c]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\ToCindent\relax}{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\myrule}{$\smash{\rule[-2mm]{1mm}{10mm}}$ } % PW ADDED

% Create the items (with different styles)
\renewcommand*{\l@chapter}[2]{%
    \l@mytocentry{\Huge \myrule #1}{#2}{\chaptername}% % PW MODIFIED
}
\renewcommand*{\l@section}[2]{%
    \l@mytocentry{\Large \myrule #1}{#2}{\sectionname}% % PW MODIFIED
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\frontmatter%
\tableofcontents*

\mainmatter%

\chapter{Welcome}
\section{A Section}
\section{Another Section}
\chapter{Hello}
\section{Yet another section}
\section{Yet another section}
\chapter{World}
\section{Yet another section}

\end{document}
```

The `\rule` macro draws a rule of the given dimension, possibly raised or lowered (as in the above case). `\smash` is a TeX mathmode macro that makes TeX think that its argument takes no vertical space. I have put these together before the `chapter` and `section` titles are printed in the ToC. Change the placement and size of the vertical rules to suit.

Comment: Just tested, rather than adding `\myrule` into the variable (this put the line right up against the text) I added a third variable to `mytocentry`:

`\noindent\parbox[c]{\ToCindent}
{\makebox[\dimexpr\ToCindent-1em][r]{\Large#2}\hfill}%\parbox[c]{1em}{\vertrule\hfill}%
 \parbox[c]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\ToCindent\relax}{#1}`

Works a charm, thank you very much!